# Cannot close or open and active or deactive ADOQuery1

Tags: delphi, ms-access

Both codes work correctly. But cannot ADOQuery1.close or ADOQuery1.open and active or deactive ADOQuery1 to view changes. To view updated changes I have to reexecute project.
Thanks in advance

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin    
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('update new set net='''+Edit1.Text+''' ' );
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('where code=16');
ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;


procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin 
ADOQuery1.Active:=false;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'update new set net=:num where code=16';
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('num').Value := Edit1.Text;
ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

Comment: Call `Refresh` on a dataset which you are using for showing your data after update.

Comment: Where is your code for retrieving records to view?  An UPDATE statement will not do that ...

Comment: @TLama IIRC with Adodatset you would need to call `Requery`.

Comment: @bummi, that's what I'm not sure about, but that would mean there is a wrong implementation of ADO dataset's `Refresh` method since `Refresh` should just refetch data.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I do it with adding second SQL(select * from table).

Comment: Do you have not enough query components? Why do you want to rule **everything** with **one** query component? It is not the **golden ring** that will rule all other. Use a query component for each of your aspects (*select*,*insert*,*update*)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a query component for **each** aspect

```
SelectQuery.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM new';
UpdateQuery.SQL.Text := 'UPDATE new SET net=:num WHERE code=16';
```

To update a record just set the parameters, execute the `UpdateQuery` and refresh the `SelectQuery`.

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin 
  UpdateQuery.Parameters.ParamByName('num').Value := Edit1.Text;
  UpdateQuery.ExecSQL;
  SelectQuery.Refresh;
end;
```

That is easy, simple and even faster, because after the first execution of the `UpdateQuery` the statement is already prepared.